# Objective C copy attribute vs copy message

Tags: ios, objective-c, copy

I have a similar code in my AppDelegate:

```
@interface AppDelegate() 
{}
@property(nonatomic, assign) UILocalNotification* mSavedLocalNotification;
@property(nonatomic, assign) UILocalNotification* tmpNotification1;
@property(nonatomic, copy) UILocalNotification* tmpNotification2;
@end



@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize mSavedLocalNotification=mSavedLocalNotification;
@synthesize tmpNotification1=tmpNotification1;
@synthesize tmpNotification2=tmpNotification2;



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *) __unused application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *) launchOptions 
    {
            UILocalNotification* notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
            if (notification)
            {
                mSavedLocalNotification = [notification copy];
                tmpNotification1 = notification;
                tmpNotification2 = notification;

                NSLog(@"########## %p %p %p %p", mSavedLocalNotification, notification, tmpNotification1, tmpNotification2);
            }
    }
```

From what I understood by reading tutorials, the copy attribute in a property should do the same thing that calling the copy method does.

So why does this program print: `0x15d39270 0x15dcc0d0 0x15dcc0d0 0x15dcc0d0 ?`

Why does the property that has the copy attribute`tmpNotification2 = notification;` just keep the same pointer instead of cloning it, while `mSavedLocalNotification = [notification copy]`; actually creates a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "copy" method doesn't copy immutable items. Since they are immutable and cannot be changed, there is no point in making a copy.

But worse, you are apparently using instance variables. You seem to be ignoring the coding convention that instance variables should start with an underscore character; you are actually actively circumventing it. That's why your mistake accessing the member variables isn't obvious.

Comment: +1 So the solution is to remove the `@synthesize` lines and let Xcode do the work.

Comment: After I removed the @synthesize part(which I added in the first place because other options didn't work) and used self.mSavedLocalNotification = notification (instead of _mSavedLocalNotification = notification), the copy attribute did what I expected it to do. I only copied an immutable object because having a strong reference wasn't working before(from the same reasons copy wasn't working).